# EAP-AKA callback for android

Tags: android

I am able to connect with EAP-AKA. but didn't find any api to know whether it is connected or not .I have implemented SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION reciever to know supplicant state .. but this reciever only helpful when any error occured.